# ui-views is not working for angular-ui-tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to use ui-tab for user page view, There are two tabs for every users 1. Profile, 2. Setting, These two tabs have separate templates. But when I click on tab, then corresponding tab is not loading.
In following example   `url: 'user/2',` is page for user id 2. I think here is something messing...

**Please find Demo**  [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiOYgY3NmVmKkPziOeXl?p=preview)

**Controller.js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router',  'ui.bootstrap']);
myapp.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'profile', view:'profile', active:true },
    { title:'setting', view:'setting', active:false }
  ];
});
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
      // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: 'user/2',
          views:{
                  '':{
                      templateUrl: 'index.html',
                      controller: 'TabsDemoCtrl',
                  },
                  'profile':{
                      templateUrl: 'profile.html'
                  },
                  'setting':{
                      templateUrl: 'setting.html'
                  },
          }
    })
});
```

**View**

```
  <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
    <uib-tabset active="active">
      <uib-tab  ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
         <div ui-view="{{tab.view}}"></div>
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your index.html file is missing ui-router files. You don't have included the necessary libraries (ui-router)

Comment: Luxor001, I have included it, plz check it `angular-ui-router.js`

Comment: Sry, but still i can't find it in the plunker you provided.

Comment: i see a bootstrap inclusion at line 6, not ui-router http://imgur.com/a/MhfAX